# Vlookup Across Sheets Type Mismatch (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup, type-mismatch

I'm trying to insert a vlookup into particular cells (J2:O2), but I keep getting type mismatches. I can't for the life of me figure out why. Here's the code I currently have:

```
Dim Basel_Sheet As Worksheet
    Set Basel_Sheet = Sheets("Basel 3 EAD")

Dim Parent_Lookup As Range
    Set Parent_Lookup = Sheets("Parent Mapping").Range("B2:E20000")

With Basel_Sheet
    .Cells(2, "J").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2," & Parent_Lookup & ",4, False)"
    ...
    ...
    ... (formulas for remaining columns)
End With
```

Should I be using `Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup` and defining a variant to store the vlookup result in instead?

Answer (score 1):

add `.Address` after `Parent_Lookup`, like the following:

**Edited to include `.Address(1, 1, xlA1, True)` per @ScottCraner**

```
Dim Basel_Sheet As Worksheet
    Set Basel_Sheet = Sheets("Basel 3 EAD")

Dim Parent_Lookup As Range
    Set Parent_Lookup = Sheets("Parent Mapping").Range("B2:E20000")

With Basel_Sheet
    .Cells(2, "J").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2," & Parent_Lookup.Address(1, 1, xlA1, True) & ",4, False)"
End With
```

Another option is to declare `Parent_Lookup` as a `String` instead of a `Range`:

```
Dim Basel_Sheet As Worksheet
    Set Basel_Sheet = Sheets("Basel 3 EAD")

Dim Parent_Lookup As String
    Parent_Lookup = "'Parent Mapping'!B2:E20000"

With Basel_Sheet
    .Cells(2, "J").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2," & Parent_Lookup & ",4, False)"
End With
```

Comment: When I do that, the range used in the vlookup is changed to the current sheet (formula has just B2:E20000), instead of the "Parent Mapping" sheet.

Comment: Need to change the range you assign.  Editing answer now

Comment: `Parent_Lookup.Address(1,1,XlA1,TRUE)`

Comment: I changed it to a string to include the Sheet name and it works `Parent_Lookup = "'Parent Mapping'!B2:E20000"` but why am I not able to use a range?

Comment: @ScottCraner that's awesome, I didn't know about that!